# Mysql join four tables and show NULL value

Tags: mysql, join, null

I need to do a query to get the result of an specific exam for each student , and I also want to display  NULL  for student who didn't enter his scores....

Here is my four table

1. `Student` table
2. `Scores` table
3. `Student`
4. `student_subject`

[image: enter image description dsds]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My table link

- Score table (user_id)  with Student table (user_id)
- Exam table ( id )  with  scores table ( exam.id)
- student_subject ( user_id ) with  student table ( user_id)
- student_subject (group_id) with exam table (group_id)  (my group database is on another database for some important reason)

My query works, but I don't have a NULL value for the student who don't have enter his score

```
SELECT 
    scores.result, students.id, exam.name, exam.id
FROM 
    scores
LEFT JOIN  
    students ON scores.user_id = students.user_id
LEFT JOIN 
    exam ON exam.id = scores.exam_id
LEFT JOIN 
    students_subjects as ss ON ss.user_id = students.id
LEFT JOIN 
    students_subjects ON students_subjects.group_id = exam.group_id
WHERE
    exam.id = 32
GROUP BY
    scores.id
```

Output

[image]

How can I get a null value for each student who don't have score for a specific exam ( exam.id = 32 ) ?

Edited for @sceaj

I got this with you're query ( I change WHERE exam.id = 34 for  WHERE exam.id = 36 for better testing)

```
SELECT scores.result,students.id,exam.name, exam.id
FROM exam
INNER JOIN students_subjects ON students_subjects.group_id = exam.group_id
INNER JOIN students ON students_subjects.user_id = students.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN scores ON scores.user_id = students.user_id
WHERE exam.id = 36
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the exam table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should return all students, with scores from exam 32 if they exist.

```
SELECT scores.result,students.id,exam.name, exam.id
FROM exam
INNER JOIN scores ON exam.id = scores.exam_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN students ON scores.user_id = students.user_id
WHERE exam.id = 32
```

Your select clause didn't use anything from students_subjects or aggregate functions, so I'm not sure what the join to it was for?  Perhaps you can start with the above and build from there.

Edit: New strategy based on my first comment.  Try and locate all students then find scores that exist, null if none.

```
SELECT scores.result,students.id,exam.name, exam.id
FROM exam
INNER JOIN students_subjects ON students_subjects.group_id = exam.group_id
INNER JOIN students ON students_subjects.user_id = students.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN scores ON scores.user_id = students.user_id
  AND scores.exam_id = exam.id
WHERE exam.id = 32
```

Comment: Ah, I think I see.  You want to restrict the output to students that should have taken exam.id = 32, but your structure of students_subject and relationship to exam is not clear to me.

Comment: students_subjects is linked with  exam for this field (  students_subjects.group_id   with  exam.group_id )   because I want to get ALL student  with  ( ex : group_id = 32)   and you're querry don't show  NULL field , thx for you're awser

Comment: The query above should return 1 row for each row in the entire student table.  Would you mind posting what result you get?

Comment: Apologies to @user1028498, LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are equivalent, I was confusing LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN.

Comment: @KevinHoude You were correct, my original solution didn't return NULL scores because the exam row would be NULL as well - I have edited my solution.

Comment: Nice we alsmost have it !  Now I have all the student in the group for this exam , but  the result field is NULL everywhere, I don't see the result of jean-chirstophe and Julianne ( null )

Comment: sorry , I made a mistake , its   student.user_id  ,  not  student.id  , I will try you're query with this

Comment: Ah, I missed that students have both id and user_id.  I had edited my solution thinking it was a typo.

Comment: I have updated my solution based on your original definition of the relationships.  I think you should have it now.

Comment: I had updated my post for show the output for you're query , I have duplicated value , and the score was not the good , only two student in this group had a notes for this exam , other had null value

Comment: The querry miss  the  link with  exam.id  with  scores.exam_id  i think

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  Try: `SELECT scores.result,students.id,exam.name, exam.id
FROM exam
INNER JOIN students_subjects ON students_subjects.group_id = exam.group_id
INNER JOIN students ON students_subjects.user_id = students.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN scores ON scores.user_id = students.user_id and scores.exam_id = exam.id
WHERE exam.id = 32`

Answer (score 0):

Don't begin with the score table, left joining all the others: you only will get lines where score is not null. Instead, do a right join, or put the scores table at the end:

```
SELECT scores.result,students.id,exam.name, exam.id
FROM 
students LEFT JOIN scores ON scores.user_id = students.user_id
LEFT  JOIN exam on exam.id = scores.exam_id
LEFT JOIN students_subjects as ss ON ss.user_id = students.id
LEFT JOIN students_subjects ON students_subjects.group_id = exam.group_id
where exam.id = 32
group by scores.id
```