# MySQL query for three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables with people, the attributes and potential value for the attributes. I can't figure out a query to display all the people, each persons attributes and their missing/null attributes. 
Here's an example table...

```
attributes
+---------------------+
| attribute_name (col)|
+---------------------+
| name                |
+---------------------+
| age                 |
+---------------------+
| gender              |
+---------------------+
| email               |
+---------------------+

people
+-----------+----------+
| person_id | value_id |
+-----------+----------+
| 2         | 7        |
+-----------+----------+
| 2         | 9        |
+-----------+----------+
| 3         | 8        |
+-----------+----------+

values
+---------------+----------------+-------+
| value_id (pk) | attribute_name | value |
+---------------+----------------+-------+
| 7             | age            | 35    |
+---------------+----------------+-------+
| 8             | age            | 28    |
+---------------+----------------+-------+
| 9             | gender         | male  |
+---------------+----------------+-------+
```

How do I join the three tables to display something like this?

```
+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| person_id | value_id | attribute_name  | value  |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| 2         | 7        | age             | 35     |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| 2         | 9        | gender          | male   |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| 2         | NULL     | name            | NULL   |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| 2         | NULL     | email           | NULL   |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| 3         | 8        | age             | 28     |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| 3         | NULL     | gender          | NULL   |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| 3         | NULL     | name            | NULL   |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| 3         | NULL     | email           | NULL   |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.person_ID, 
        MAX(c.value_ID) value_ID, 
        b.attribute_name ,  
        MAX(c.value) Value
FROM    people a
        CROSS JOIN attributes b       
        LEFT JOIN `values` c
            ON  a.value_ID = c.value_ID AND
                b.attribute_name = c.attribute_name
GROUP BY a.person_ID, b.attribute_name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5640/14)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to set everything up JW. This was exactly what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a join of the three tables with a WHERE Statement (SQL Basics).

Did you do a search before posting?

For null there is this post [MySQL Show Null Results in Query - With INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014631/mysql-show-null-results-in-query-with-inner-join) or this [Mysql join four tables and show NULL value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011171/mysql-join-four-table-and-show-null-value)

;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    person_id,
    attributes.attribute_name as attribute_name,
    values.value as value
from people
cross join attributes
left join values on people.value_id=values.value_id
                and attributes.attribute_name=values.attribute_name
```

Comment: The problem is displaying the missing attributes each person may have.

Comment: This was the most concise but I was getting a few duplicates. Thank you for taking the time to contribute Saddam

Answer (score 0):

Using your expected output as a starting point, you essentially want the cross product of attributes and distinct people from `people` to be left joined to the result of a(n inner) join of `people` to `values`. And this is how you could script that in SQL (particularly in MySQL):

```
SELECT
  p.person_id,
  v.value_id,
  a.attribute_name,
  v.value
FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT person_id FROM people) p
  CROSS JOIN attributes a
  LEFT JOIN
    people d
    INNER JOIN `values` v ON d.value_id = v.value_id
  ON p.person_id = d.person_id
  AND a.attribute_name = v.attribute_name
;
```

Comment: Thanks Andriy for your approach.